# Is it possible to solve and find out the square of the matrix value answer without calculating?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

There is a matrix  $A =$

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 1 & -b & -b\\ -1 & a & a \end{pmatrix}

where $a-b = 1$ . $A^2$ is an Identity matrix of order $3$ . Is it possible to find $A^2$ without even calculating $A^2$ ? Please help .

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want to calculate $A^2$? It seems to me like the most direct way to answer the problem.

Comment: I want to know if there is any other way to find $A^2$ using elementary row operations or any matrix rules

Comment: It looks like you wrote the answer in your question already ("A^2 is an identity matrix of order 3").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's another way. It's certainly not easier, but it works. I suspect it uses a number of ideas that you have not yet encountered as well, but that's how life is sometimes. Anyhow, here goes:

First, you can compute the characteristic polynomial, $c(x) = \det(A - xI)$, which is 
\begin{align}
c(x) 
&= \det \pmatrix{-x & a & b \\ 1 & -b - x & -b \\ -1 & a & a - x}\\
&= (-x) \left( (-b-x)(a-x) + ab\right) - a \left( (a-x) -b \right) + b \left(a + (-b-x) \right)\\
&= x \left( (b+x)(a-x) - ab\right) - a \left( a-x -b \right) + b \left(a -b-x \right) & \text{substitute $a-b = 1$ to get}\\
&= x \left( (b+x)(a-x) - ab\right) - a \left( 1-x \right) + b \left(1-x \right) \\
&= x \left( ba + (a-b)x - x^2 - ab\right) - a \left( 1-x \right) + b \left(1-x \right) \\
&= x \left(x - x^2 \right) - a \left( 1-x \right) + b \left(1-x \right) \\
&= x^2 - x^3 + (b-a)\left( 1-x \right) \\
&= x^2 - x^3 -1\left( 1-x \right) \\
&= x^2 - x^3 -1 + x \\
&= -x^3 + x^2 + x -1 \\
&= -(x-1)^2(x+1)
\end{align}
That means that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1, 1, -1$. Hence the Jordan normal form of $A$ is either 
$$
A= P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} P
$$
or
$$
A= P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 1& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} P
$$
for some invertible matrix $P$.

In the first case, there are two eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$; in the second there's only one. We can check which of these happens by looking at the nullspace of $A - 1 \cdot I$, whose dimension is the number of eigenvectors for $+1$:

\begin{align}
A - 1 \cdot I = 
\pmatrix{-1 & a & b \\
1 & -b-1 & -b \\
-1 & a & a-1} & \text{substitute $a = b+1; a-1 = b$}\\
=\pmatrix{-1 & b+1 & b \\
1 & -(b+1) & -b \\
-1 & b+1 & b} 
\end{align}
The second and third columns are obviously multiples of the first, so $A - 1 \cdot I$ has rank $1$, i.e., there are two eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $1$. That means that for some matrix $P$, we have
$$
A= P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} P
$$
whence

\begin{align}
A^2 
&= 
(P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} P)
(P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} P) \\
&= 
P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} (P
P^{-1}) \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1} P \\
&= 
P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1}^2 P \\
&= 
P^{-1} \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} P \\
&= 
P^{-1} I P \\
&= 
P^{-1} P \\
&= 
I. 
\end{align}

It seems to me that it would have been a great deal easier to just compute $A^2$ directly. :)

Comment: what is $P$ here ?

Comment: In the Jordan Normal form, a theorem guarantees that there's *some* (square) matrix $P$ with the property that $P^{-1} A P$ is in "Jordan normal form". The exact nature of the matrix $P$ doesn't matter for this particular line of argument, however. I've added a phrase to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. It is not as nice as the other answer, but it is shorter. Perform the elementary row operations (in C programming language's notation):
`row 3 += row 2; col 2 -= col 3`. We see that $A$ is similar to
$$
B=\pmatrix{
0&1&b\\
1&0&-b\\
0&0&1}.
$$
One can verify that $\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 0},\pmatrix{1\\ -1\\ 0}$ and $\pmatrix{b\\ -b\\ 2}$ are eigenvectors of $B$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $1,-1$ and $1$ respectively. When the underlying field is not of characteristic $2$, these eigenvectors are linearly independent. Therefore $B$ and in turn $A$ are similar to $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,1)$. Hence their squares are equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: Kindly explain "When the underlying field is not of characteristic 2, these eigenvectors are linearly independent. Therefore B and in turn A are similar to diag(1,−1,1) Hence their squares are equal to the identity matrix."

Comment: @NilabjaSaha The first two vectors have zero last entries, therefore the third vector cannot be a linear combination of the first two. And the first two vectors are not parallel to each other. Hence all three vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: "Therefore B and in turn A are similar to diag(1,−1,1) . Hence their squares are equal to the identity matrix." - Please explain this .

Answer (score 0):

What??  If "$A^2$ is the identity matrix" then $A^3= A(A^2)= A$.  No "calculation" at all required!

Answer (score 0):

A solution without calculation.

from $tr(A)=a-b=1$, we deduce that

$A^2=I$ IFF $A$ is diagonalizable and $\{1,1\}\subset spectrum(A)$

IFF $rank(A-I)=1$.

Clearly, we see that  $rank(A-I)=rank\begin{pmatrix}-1&b+1&b\\1&-b-1&-b\\-1&b+1&b\end{pmatrix}=1$.